# Can you use Linq to find relationships between elements in a collection?

Tags: c#, linq, querying

I have a List of Data, and I want to find the length of the longest sequence of elements in the list that are equal.  This is easy to do with a loop over the collection, however I was wondering if there is a Linq query that can do this.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Paste the code with the loop, we have no idea what your data is like..

Comment: It shouldn't matter, all that matters is that the element type supports equality comparison.  Pretend it's a List of integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var longest = list.Select((x,i) => list.Skip(i).TakeWhile(c => c == x).Count()).Max();
```

Comment: Note that you do a lot of counting over and over again needlessly...This is O(n^2) when it could be O(n).  If that matter to the OP...

Comment: Yes, looping could be significantly faster for large lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the sequence incrementing a counter when an item is equal to the previous and resetting it if it's not.

```
public static int LongestSequence<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext()) //empty sequence
            return 0;
        T previous = iterator.Current;
        int count = 1;
        int maxCount = 1;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(iterator.Current, previous))
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                maxCount = Math.Max(maxCount, count);
                count = 1;
                previous = iterator.Current;
            }
        }

        return maxCount;
    }
}
```